# my click function for delete can't show after add Chart script

Tags: javascript, php, chart.js

Why doesn't my `click()` function for delete won't show after add Chart script

My script is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
        $(".delete").click(function(){
        var element = $(this);
        var del_id = element.attr("id");
        var info = 'id=' + del_id;
        if(confirm("Apakah Anda Yakin Ingin Mengapus Data ini ?")){
         $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "hapus.php",
           data: info,
           success: function(){
             window.location = 'home.php';
         }
        });
          $(this).parents(".show").animate({ backgroundColor: "#003" }, "slow")
          .animate({ opacity: "hide" }, "slow");
         }
        return false;
        });
        });

    //javascript for ChartJS
    var linechart = document.getElementById('line-cpu');
    var chart = new Chart(linechart, {
      type: 'line',
      data: {
        labels: <?php echo json_encode($data_tanggal) ?>, // Merubah data tanggal menjadi format JSON
        datasets: [{
          label: 'Persentase Penggunaan CPU',
          data: <?php echo json_encode($data_cpu) ?>,
          borderColor: 'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
          backgroundColor: 'transparent',
          borderWidth: 2
        }]
      }
    });

 </script>
```

And for html code I'm using is this:

```
<a class='btn btn-danger delete'  href="#" id="<?php echo $srvid; ?>"><i class="halflings-icon trash" title="Hapus Service"></i></a>
```

JavaScript `click()` function delete ran normally before JavaScript for ChartJS add, can you help me how to fix this?

Comment: Do you get any errors in your console? Also what is the output of `<?php echo json_encode($data_tanggal) ?>`?